# Number of solutions to $x+y+z=n$ with constraints.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given three nonnegative integers each from $0-500$  (which are not necessarily distinct) what's the probability the sum equals $1000$.

I know the denominator is $501^3$. I also know that the number of nonnegative solutions to $(x+1)+(y+1)+(x+1)=1000+3$ is,

$${1002 \choose 2}$$

Because, to find this I write $1003$ ones using $1002$ addition signs,

$$1003=1+1...+1$$

Then by choosing $2$ plus signs to delete out of $1002$ I'm making $3$ groups of $1's$ and hence finding a solution.

Now what about with the constraints, what do I subtract off?

I need to subtract of the solutions that use $501,502,.....1000$. But I can't figure out how to get that quantity.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If a solution uses $501 \leq k \leq 1000$, then the other two numbers add to $1000-k$. It is easy to figure out how many solutions use each vaulue $501 \leq k \leq 1000$ and add these numbers together.

Comment: Ok thanks. I let you know what I get.

Comment: I got $\sum_{k=1}^{500} k=\frac{500(501)}{2}$ as what I need to subtract out. I assume I don't need to worry the conditions on the two other numbers because if $1000-501<501$ then there is no way I'll get a solution by choosing anything over $500$. Is that good?

Comment: Actually would I have to multiply by $3$ because I can put the $k$ in any of three positions?